# How to facilitate OCamljava compilation of ocaml library with C function calls?

Tags: java, c, build, ocaml

I'm using ocamljava, and it's working beautifully. It's very natural, admitting the whole of the ocaml language with a simple compiler name exchange in most cases being all that is required in order to compile to java byte-code and then produce a workable jar.

So, I need to use java for the libraries that it has, but ocaml has a very respectable library that I want to take advantage of. I don't want to redo any work at all really. The problem is, as far as I know, ocamljava doesn't support callbacks into C code from ocaml using the simple process admitted by each of the ocamlc and ocamlopt compilers. So compilation is stuck; but am I wrong-is it true that ocamljava does not have this support yet? It seems clear to me that java can call into C, it should be possible to generate java-byte-code that makes this call equivalently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, ocamlc and the ocamlopt compilers make use of the ctypes backend that facilitates a language runtime difference, where C functions can be called. But C types doesn't take into consideration the problem of specifying in ocaml the calling of C functions from the context of the JVM or for that matter how to force the ocaml compiler to select the correct method of delegating to C functions at compile time.

What is needed, therefore, is a new "backend" for ctypes, which would enable the above, possibly through the use of JNA. This much is suggested by Xavier himself, as I have discussed it directly with him. It's on the map, but not necessarily prioritized.